# Laravel-Excel two-row headings where some headings span multiple columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Is it possible to achieve 2-row headings with Laravel-Excel? If so, is it possible to make it span multiple columns for certain headings?

I need the following table structure:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|          |  Header 2 - Multiple Columns  |          |
-----------------------------------------------------
| Header 1 | Header 2-Sub1 | Header 2-Sub2 | Header 3 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now in my export file I have a simple headings method which only returns a single row headings:

```
public function headings()
{
    return ['col1', 'col2', ...];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a 2d array ([documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/csv/1.0/exports/heading-row.html#multiple-rows)):

```php
public function headings()
{
    return [
        ['', 'Header 2 - Multiple Columns', ''],
        ['Header 1', 'Header 2-Sub1', 'Header 2-Sub2', 'Header 3'],
    ];
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to justify the headers, Do as follow:

```php
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->mergeCells('B1:C1'); // Merge cells for Header 2 - Multiple Columns
            },
        ];
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            [' ', 'Header 2 - Multiple Columns', ' ' , ' '],
            ['Header 1', 'Header 2-Sub1', 'Header 2-Sub2', 'Header 3'],
        ];
    }
```

Here we add 3 empty columns (`' '`) to the first row. Then we merge `B1` with `C1`.

> Remember to implement `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents` concern in the class

Comment: It's really close, however the problem is that `Header 2 - Multiple Columns` does not span 2 columns, so it will just have 3 columns at the top and 4 columns at the bottom which is not aligned